# How do I interface with the "cprman" clock manager from another kernel module?

Tags: kernel, system-clock

It's relatively simple to control the clock manager registers.  I've found a set of values, and have C code that writes the desired values to the clock manager registers.  This works well; that part of the problem is solved for me.

However, now I'm trying to incorporate that functionality into a kernel module. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7738534/415551) makes it clear that a kernel module shall request IO memory prior to using it.  So far so good.

However, this memory is already reserved by another module.  Running `sudo cat /proc/iomem` tells me that this other module is called `cprman`:

`$ sudo cat /proc/iomem
... irrelevant ...
3f101000-3f102fff : /soc/cprman@7e101000
... irrelevant ...`

A quick google search [reveals](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/clock/brcm%2Cbcm2835-cprman.txt) that this is a kernel module dedicated to clock management.  Great!

Does anyone know how to interface, from C, with this module?  I would like to command a clock configuration, in the "right way".  I have code that steps around the other kernel module and modifies the clock control registers directly.  What I want is to play nice, and make the request through the piece of code that's supposed to be managing the clocks.